# Unexpected token 'catch' in C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\views\partials\messages.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

***Someone Please help***

this is my error

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\views\register.ejs:7
    5|                          <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
    6|                  </h1>
 >> 7|                  <%- include ('partials/messages.ejs') %>
    8|                  <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
    9|                          <div class="form-group">
    10|                                         <label for="name">Name</label>

Unexpected token 'catch' in C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\views\partials\messages.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
    at includeFile (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:321:10)
    at include (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:689:16)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12), <anonymous>:10:17)
    at register (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\html codes\portfolio\passport-tutorial\routes\users.js:38:7
```

this is the register.ejs file

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
            </h1>
            <%- include ('partials/messages') %>
            <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="name"
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Name"
                        value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Email"
                        value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? email : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Create Password"
                        value="<%= typeof password != 'undefined' ? password : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password2"
                        name="password2"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Confirm Password"
                        value="<%= typeof password2 != 'undefined' ? password2 : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                    Register
                </button>
            </form>
            <p class="lead mt-4">
                Have An Account? <a href="/users/login">Login</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the login.ejs file

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login
            </h1>
            <%- include ('partials/messages') %>
            <form action="/users/login" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Email"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Password"
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                    Login
                </button>
            </form>
            <p class="lead mt-4">
                No Account? <a href="/users/register">Register</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***this is my partial messeges.ejs***

```
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %> <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= error.msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<% }); %> <% } %> <% if(success_msg != ''){ %>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= success_msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<% } %> <% if(error_msg != ''){ %>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= error_msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

this is my users.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

//User model
const User = require("../models/User");

//Login page
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});

//Register page
router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("register");
});

//Registration Post Handler
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    //Check required fields
    if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Please fill in all fields" });
    }

    if (password !== password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Passwords do not match" });
    }

    //Check password length
    if (password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Password must be at least 6 characters long" });
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render("register", {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2,
        });
    } else {
        //validating user
        User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                // if User exist
                errors.push({ msg: "Email already exist" });
                res.render("register", {
                    errors,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    password2,
                });
            } else {
                const newUser = new User({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                });

                //Hashing Password
                bcrypt.genSalt(10, (error, salt) =>
                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (error, hash) => {
                        if (error) throw error;

                        //setting password to hash
                        newUser.password = hash;

                        //save user
                        newUser
                            .save()
                            .then((user) => {
                                req.flash('success_msg','You are now registered and can now sign in')
                                res.redirect("/users/login");
                                // console.log(newUser)
                            })
                            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
                    })
                );
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have checked github and other online resources butI have not found anything tangible. I have tried earlier versions of ejs, but still have the same problem.

It was working fine until i brought in connect-flash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<%- include('./partials/messages.ejs'); %> ` try this

Comment: I just tried it but am still getting the same error

Comment: what version of `ejs` are you using?

Comment: The current version 3.1.3

Comment: this is the github repo link https://github.com/Dominic2000code/Passport_app

Comment: Okay, I got it you missed closing tag `<% } %>` after the last div.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. I cant thank you enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for necro-ing the question. The problem is that you're missing the closing of your third `if` block in the "messages.ejs" partial. I had the same problem 10 minutes ago and found your question

```js
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %> <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= error.msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<% }); %> <% } %> <% if(success_msg != ''){ %>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= success_msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- you opened an "if" block here, but didn't close it !-->
<!-- also closing the EJS after the previous closing tag, and reopening it before the next "if" statement isn't necessary !-->
<% } %> <% if(error_msg != ''){ %>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= error_msg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- Needs the closing tag for the "if" block here --!>
<% } %>
```